# popCalander.js in modalpopUp exender

Tags: modalpopupextender

I am having a date picker in an ajax modalpopupextender. I am generating the calendar control using the popcalander.js but it is generating error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of null". In popCalander.js for setting the position of the calendar popup this offset from the parent container is using, But the container is null when i used the modalpopupExtender.

Please guide me

Thanks,

Nithin Abraham Paul